# How to issue multiple prompts to a user, depending on how many times they wish to be prompted C++

Tags: c++, string, input, reference, cin

I am creating a program in C++ that allows a user to input the number of times he or she wants to be prompted for three separate inputs, ie.

```
how many would you like: 2
enter here: 123.45/N 32.45/W Los Angeles
enter here: 22.22/N 223.4/E Hong Kong
```

The way I get the three separate inputs is by creating three string variables, and doing this:

```
cin << input1 << input2;
getline(cin, input3);
```

I have a parser in a separate file that I created that gets the number input out of the first two strings and does some calculations on it.

The problem I'm having is visualizing how to set up a system only using the std library, where I can have the user enter the number of times they want to input places, and then have the program create 3 unique strings I can reference later for calculations, and have it do cin/getline the amount of times the user enters.

One way I thought of was creating a function that takes an integer (the amount the user entered) and goes through a for loop which calls cin and getline. The problem with that is, how do I save and reference the values the user inputs for calculations later on? ie.

```
void inputAmount(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin << input1 << input2;
        getline(cin, input3);
    }
}
```

Where n is the amount of lines the user wants to enter. I tried to create an array of strings and initializing it with (n * 3) elements, but that apparently doesn't work with C++ since the variable must be constant and declared. I'm just confused on how to proceed, or how to achieve this.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what you can and can't use from the std library?

Comment: Not many restrictions that I know of, just have to use basic tools though. I've seen stuff like a boost function and some other crazy things, but my class has literally only learned about references and arrays.

Comment: Can you use a `std::vector`?

Comment: I'll go ahead and assume yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of an array. A `std::vector` does not require a size at compile time. Your code would look something like this:

```
string input1, input2, input3;
int n; // number of lines
vector<string> v; // vector to hold the lines

// prompt user for number of lines
cout << "how many lines?" << endl;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  cin << input1 << input2;
  getline(cin, input3);
  // parse and put back into input1, input2, etc. or some other variable as needed
  v.push_back(input1);
  v.push_back(input2);
  v.push_back(input3);
}
```

The call to `push_back()` adds the element to the `vector`. You can access the elements with an iterator or with the `[]` operator (same as an array). It would probably be better to create a `struct` to store the three inputs together, in which case you would parameterize the `vector` with your `struct` instead of a `string`, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Sorry I'm replying late.. so I'm trying to figure out how to access each element of the vector. Ie. lets say the user wants to enter 2 versions of input, which would mean 6 input variables, would the vector account for that each time I push an input back into the vector? Ie. push_back(input1) would be accessible at v[0] and then when it runs again, another, different version of input1 is created that I can access at v[0] while the first input1 is at v[5]?

Comment: @Alex The vector will continue to add new strings to the end for every call to `push_back()`. The first run through the `for` loop will put `input1` in `v[0]`, `input2` in `v[1]`, etc. The second run through the `for` loop will put `input1` (with the new information from the user for the second triplet) in `v[3]`, `input2` in `v[4]`, and `input3` in `v[5]`.